# Minimum size of 2D barcode that a 2MP mobile camera can scan

Tags: mobile, 2d, barcode-scanner

I am getting a mobile application done. I want to know what is minimum size of 2D barcode that a 2MP mobile camera can scan.

Barcodes what I am printing is <1cm

Regards,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

For small barcodes, it's hard to make the camera focus correcly, so from a usability point of view, you should test different sizes.